# How ca I change this class to make immutable methods?

Tags: java, immutability, account, bank

I tried to read up on immutable methods but I still do not understand.
I want to change the BankAccount class' methods to be immutable how can I do that?

```
public class BankAccount
{
  private double balance;

  public BankAccount()
  {
    balance = 0;
  }

  public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
  {
    balance = initialBalance;
  }

  public void deposit(double amount)
  {
    balance = balance + amount;
  }

  public void withdraw(double amount)
  {
    balance = balance - amount;
  }

  public double getBalance()
  {
    return balance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has no const qualifier. You cannot tell the compiler that "getBalance()" method does not modify the class.

The class itself is not immutable because it contains mutator methods. And it's probably a good idea for a BankAccount to be modifiable. But if you wanted instances to be immutable, you could do so by:

- Removing the modifier methods
- Marking the fields final
- Marking the class final
- Making defensive copies of objects received and returned. (In this case, there are no objects received or returned.)

Comment: I see.  Can you give an example for one of them so I may understand a bit better?

Comment: Here are two: public final class BankAccount { 
  private final double balance;